# Given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers without division?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was recently asked the following interview question over the phone:

> Given an array of integers, produce an array whose values are the
>   product of every other integer excluding the current index.
>
> Example:
>
> [4, 3, 2, 8] -> [3*2*8, 4*2*8, 4*3*8, 4*3*2] -> [48, 64, 96, 24]

I came up with below code:

```
public static BigInteger[] calcArray(int[] input) throws Exception {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input is null");
    }
    BigInteger product = calculateProduct(input);
    BigInteger result[] = new BigInteger[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        result[i] = product.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(input[i]));
    }
    return result;
}

private static BigInteger calculateProduct(int[] input) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(input[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Complexity:

```
Time Complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(n)
```

Can we do this in O(n) complexity without division?  Also is there any way to reduce space complexity if use simple primitive integer array.

Comment: *Posted earlier by [@mettleap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10402819/mettleap):* You can find the algorithm here: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-product-array-puzzle/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-product-array-puzzle/)

Comment: By `without division` you mean without ONLY `/` ?

Comment: yeah I think so. Does it mean something else as well?

Comment: @John Ok, I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an element located at index `i`. Look to its left, lets say we have a product of elements till the index `i-1`. Lets call it `leftProduct[i]` that is product of all elements to the left of element at `i`. Similarly lets call `rightProduct[i]` is product of all elements to the right of element at `i`.
Then the result for that index is `output[i] = leftProduct[i]*rightProduct[i]`

Now think about how to get `leftProduct`. You simply traverse the array from start and compute a running product and at each element update the `leftProduct` with the current running product.
Similarly you can compute `rightProduct` by traversing the array from the end. Here you can optimize the space by reusing the `leftProduct` array by updating it with multiplying the `rightProduct`.

The below code demonstrates this:

```
public static int[] getProductsExcludingCurrentIndex( int[] arr ) {
     if ( arr == null || arr.length == 0 ) return new int[]{};
     int[] leftProduct = new int[arr.length];
     int runningProduct = 1;
     //Compute left product at each i
     for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
       leftProduct[i] = runningProduct;
       runningProduct = runningProduct*arr[i];
    }
    runningProduct = 1;
    //By reverse traversal, we compute right product but at the same time update the left 
    //product, so it will have leftProduct*rightProduct
    for ( int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        leftProduct[i] = leftProduct[i]*runningProduct;
        runningProduct = runningProduct*arr[i];
    }
    return leftProduct;
}
```

Space complexity is `O(n)` - we use only one array `leftProduct`, time complexity is `O(n)`.

- Space complexity edit:

But if you don't consider the space used for storing output, then this is `O(1)`, because we are storing output in `leftProduct` itself.

If you strictly don't want extra space then that entails modifying your input array. Solving this by modifying input array as you go is not possible at all at least as far as I know.

Comment: make sense now.. also is there any way to do this in constant space complexity O(1)? just wondering.

Comment: @john I added a comment on space complexity to the answer. please check.

Answer (score 0):

My thought:

- Take product all numbers and store it in a variable `result`.
- Now, for each element, answer is `result / arr[i]`.
- So, do a binary search from `1` to `result/2` for each element `arr[i]` to get the `quotient` which is the answer for each arr[i].
- Time complexity: O(n * (log(n)), Space Complexity: O(1).